# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QRcode'

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian

For some reason I get AttributeError.
[image]

My code in Genie is:

```
import qrcode
import cv2 

qr = qrcode.QRCode()

text=raw_input("Insert text to generate: ")
qr.add_data(text)
qr.make()
img = qr.make_image(fill_color="#000000", back_color="#ffffff")
img.save('code.png')

img = cv2.imread('code.png')  
cv2.imshow('QR Code', img) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to generate a QR code through python, but I get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first upgrading pip, then installing qrcode as described at PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)

1. upgrade pip

`pip install --upgrade pip`

2. use pip to install qrcode from PyPi

`pip install qrcode[pil]`

*Note:* I did these two steps in a python virtual environment for python v3.8.  Later will try again with 3.11.1 and will try to circle back to this thread if/when I get that working.

I followed these instructions for my python3 virtual env:  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

`python3 -m venv tutorial-env`

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
qr = qrcode.QRCode  (C in uppercase)
```

in your code in error line

not

```
qr = qrcode.QRcode (C in lowercase)
```